# Typescript file in Chrome devtool is different than code in VS Code

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

So I've been struggling to debug this typescript file we have in our enterprise app. Let's call it `fetch-effects.ts`, it's a typescript file for ngrx/effects. I know there's a Chrome Debugger extension for visual studio code, but I can't get it to work since our app is structured oddly, it has an HostApp that needs to be run, along with one of the child apps, the child app is an iframe inside the HostApp. Both of them are running simultaneously on different ports locally on my machine.

Anyway, I can't get debugger to work with VS Code, and the team just told me to place `debugger;` in the code and check Chrome Devtools in the browser. But I've been doing trying to debug this .ts file and it's showing different code in Devtools compared to my code in VS Code. Like the debugger hits on the right file in a random line, but the file itself is not exact copy of my code in VS Code. I've tried restarting chrome, and hard refresh, but I've only managed to make it show up the same 1 time. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI?

Comment: are u debugging running `ng serve` of you debugging like `ng build` / `ng build --prod --sourcemaps` output or any other `custom toolchain(webpack)` output? Is your `vscode debugger` and `chrome debugger` pointed to the same source?

Comment: @cgTag yeah, angular CLI

Comment: @Kuncevic both apps are ran with `npm start`, and the script inside `package.json` has these: `"start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "build": "npm run sass & ng build && npm run tslint >> dist/HostApp-tslint-warnings.csv"`. I'm not too familiar with this to check the rest of your suggestions tho...